# Search in Elasticsearch for a string containing the "not" keyword

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, kibana

I am using ElasticSearch on AWS (7.9 version) and I am trying to distinguish between two strings.

My main target is to split the search results on "Found" and on "Not found".

The generic question is how to search for "not" keyword.

Two example messages you can see below.

```
 "CachingServiceOne:Found in cache - Retrieve."
 "CachingServiceThree:Not found in cache - Create new."
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [ngram tokenizer](http://elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html), to search for `"not"` on `"title"` field.

Adding a working example with index data, mapping, search query, and search result

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "my_tokenizer"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "my_tokenizer": {
          "type": "ngram",
          "min_gram": 3,
          "max_gram": 5,
          "token_chars": [
            "letter",
            "digit"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "max_ngram_diff": 10
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "title": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index Data:**

```
{
    "title":"CachingServiceThree:Not found in cache - Create new."
}
{
    "title":"CachingServiceOne:Found in cache - Retrieve."
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query":{
    "match":{
      "title":"Not"
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "67093372",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 0.6720003,
        "_source": {
          "title": "CachingServiceThree:Not found in cache - Create new."
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: Well, that definitely will work.
Thought there was something I was missing.
A follow up question, if I may.
It is common practice to write your own analyzers? It's not that they create much of an overhead.

Comment: @cr3a7ure if no analyzer is specified, elasticsearch uses a standard analyzer. So, if you have a particular use case, then you need to define your own custom analzyer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the problem seems to be indeed the way the default analyzer works, and not the fact that I could not search for the `not` word. That is why I accepted the answer. But I would like to add another take. For the sake of simplicity.

1. Default analyzer does not split words on `:`.
2. That means, we have to search for `title:CachingServiceThree\:Not`.
3. Where `title` is the field name and `:` must be escaped `\:`.

What did the trick was `title:*\:Not` and `title:*\:Found` using the KQL syntax.

Using the [wildcard](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/7.9/kuery-query.html#_wildcard_queries) did the trick to fetch everything. I am wondering whether using an array of all the actual values will be quicker.

That translated through the Inspect panel into:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "query_string": {
                  "fields": [
                    "title"
                  ],
                  "query": "*\\:Not"
                }
              }
            ],
            "minimum_should_match": 1
          }
        }
      ]
    }
 }
}
```